# Add more android "name" in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, sugarcrm

I use Sugar ORM in my application. I also declared a class that extends Application. Now I have a problem, In order to use Sugar ORM I need to include this in Manifest :

```
android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
```

But I need also an android name for MyApplication that extends Application. How can I do that ?  Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm new to Android.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have `MyApplication` extend `com.orm.SugarApp` instead of `Application`.